# Can I develop on Google Glass outside of the US?

Tags: google-glass

we have received an invite to the Google Glass Explorer Program and it says Explorers must be be U.S. residents. Is the device or software geo-restricted? So if we buy Glass in the US and get it shipped inside the US, can we then forward and develop on the device in the UK and Romania? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a licensing (legal) question, and is not programming related in accordance with the [help] guidelines. It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Only US resident can buy google glass for now but it can be used anywhere. And now the mirror API is open to public so everyone even without an invite can develop glassware.